# ¿Cómo utilizar Net-send con sql server?

Tags: sql-server, windows

Sé que se puede o se podía utilizar ya que encontré una guía donde lo gane, fuera de esto la información es muy escasa. Estoy utilizando la versión 2019 de SQL server Standar

La información de la guía es muy explicita y todo está explicado paso por paso pero no me aparecen las mismas opciones en el SQL server.
Anexo imagenes de la interfaz que tengo.
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
No sé si debo de agregar complementos al instalador, de antemano gracias.

Anexo link de la guía que encontré
http://www.udb.edu.sv/udb_files/recursos_guias/informatica-ingenieria/base-de-datos-i/2019/i/guia-13.pdf

Comment: La guía es bastante vieja. Es posible que no encuentres las mismas opciones.

Answer (score 0):

La ayuda dice que requiere Microsoft Windows Messenger para enviar el mensaje. No creo que siga siendo algo viable puesto que está descontinuado. En todo caso podrías generar un paso adicional que sea de tipo cmdexec y ese mande el net send. Tienes que configurar para que en caso de error todos los pasos apunten a ese, y en caso de éxito del último paso real, termine el job.

Comment: Gracias por la respuesta  bb